# Determine if string is zeroish in PHP

Tags: php

I need to determine if a string variable is zeroish in `php` i.e.

```
//is zeroish true
"0"

//is zeroish true
"000"

//is zeroish true
"0000000000000000"

//is zeroish false
"00001000"
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Is `""` zeroish? Is `"a"` zeroish? Is `"0x0"` zeroish? Is `"false"` zeroish? Is `"zero"` zeroish? Is `"0.0"` zeroish? Is `"0e1"` zeroish? Please **define** zeroish.

Answer (score 2):

There's bunch of ways to do this. Here's a few:

```
if (strlen(str_replace('0', '', $string)) === 0)  {
    // zeroish
}

if (empty(str_replace('0', '', $string)))  {
    // zeroish
}

if (!preg_match('/[^0]/', $string))  {
    // zeroish
}  

if (preg_match('/^(0)\1*$/', $string)) {
    // zeroish
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
if(strlen(trim($str,"0")==0){
    echo "it is zeroish"
}
```

This just cuts off all zeros from the end of the string, and if there is anything left over, it will say it is not zeroish

Answer (score 0):

Use intval. It returns the integer value of a string.
Example -

```
if(intval($str)==0){
   echo "ZEROISH";
}
```

Comment: if it has string it'll return 0

Answer (score 0):

```
function isZeroish($number) {
    return ! (int) $number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

very simple.

```
if (!preg_match('/[^0]/', $str)) { // search for non-zero chars
  echo "ZEROISH";
}
```